# ts Cannot find name ... with typeRoots specified explicity

Tags: typescript, types

I am working on a monorepo structure for my TypeScript 3.0.3 project, simplified structure looks like this

```
_types/
  models.ts
package.json
tsconfig.json
packages/
  app/
    tsconfig.json
    package.json
  server/
    tsconfig.json
    package.json
```

So, I put my global interfaces inside `_types` folder, example of `models.ts` looks like this

```
interface ICharacterEssentials {
  username: string
  gender: 'MALE' | 'FEMALE'
  skinTone: 'DARK' | 'LIGHT'
  race: 'HUMAN' | 'ORC' | 'ELF' | 'DWARF'
}
```

This interface is than used inside my `packages/server/index.ts` file, however I get error

> [ts] Cannot find name 'ICharacterEssentials'.

My initial instinct was that it doesn't see this as interface file is outside of `/packages/server` folder. So I went into my monorepos root `tsconfig.json` and added this bit inside `compilerOptions`

```
"typeRoots": [
  "./_types/*",
  "./node_modules"
]
```

My `packages/server/tsconfig.json` file extends this like so

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "outDir": "./dist"
  },
  "exclude": [
   "./dist"
  ]
}
```

I assumed this would make my `ICharacterEssentials` interface visible inside my server package, but I still get same error. Any advice on how to resolve this? (while also preserving type definitions of my node modules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you are not **exporting** the interface. Try:

```
export interface ICharacterEssentials {
  username: string
  gender: 'MALE' | 'FEMALE'
  skinTone: 'DARK' | 'LIGHT'
  race: 'HUMAN' | 'ORC' | 'ELF' | 'DWARF'
}
```

You stated that the reason for this configuration on `tsconfig.json`...

```
"typeRoots": [
  "./_types/*",
  "./node_modules"
]
```

... was an attempt to make the root types visible inside the packages. This is unnecessary. TypeScript will automatically look for types anywhere, if you don't specify it. One reason you might want to do so, though, is to prevent the root of your monorepo to access types defined inside each individual package. That is up to you.

Extending the base `tsconfig.json` inside each package is not necessary for type resolution. I would go even further and ask you to question whether you want individual `tsconfig.json` for each package in the monorepo. I work on a big TypeScript monorepo and we don't have individual `tsconfig.json` for each package.

Back to your question. Interestingly, Visual Studio Code did not suggest an auto-import of the outer `ICharacterEssentials` inside the nested folder, on my test project, but WebStorm did, and of course, it works regardless of the editor.

[image]

Comment: Main reason for extending these is to add per project things like `jsx` support in our react packages, which is not needed in server for example.

I removed `typeRoots` and added exports to all interfaces, but issue still persists :/  This did work when I only had 1 tsconfig.json at root, I think somehow those nested ones are not finding / looking for types outside of the folders they are in. Is there any way to make them look for types outside?

Comment: @lija, can you make sure you are importing the interface as I showed on the image I pasted? Because it is working perfectly for me.